# How to slowdown the camera PreviewCallback frequency?

Tags: android, camera

I am working on a long-run service in Android phone to monitor user behavior via front camera.  The Camera.PreviewCallback() interface wastes to much battery, cpu cycles and memory on 30 fps.  How can I slow down the callback frequency to 1 fps?

I suppose there are two approaches to achieve the goal.

1. check timestamp whenever the onPreviewFrame() is called.  If the function is called too frequent, just return to skip the heavy load image processing.
2. create a thread to call setOneShotPreviewCallback() every second.

Which one is better?  Or someone can advise me the best way?